# Fick's Law dependency on concentration or pressure gradients

Tags: transport-phenomena

The question is about the Fick's law dependency on pressure. Would the gas molecules still flow through a membrane in case there is no concentration gradient but still a pressure gradient (e.g. containers at different temperature)?

Answer (score 1):

Fick's law doesn't depend on the pressure difference because a constant pressure is assumed during the derivation. If you don't have a constant pressure, you need take one step backwards from Fick's equations - and diffusion, in general. If you are looking for a relatively simple equation to describe membrane transport due to pressure difference, I suggest checking out [Darcy's law instead.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%27s_law)

Comment: I understand [Darcy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%27s_law) is applicable to  incompressible flows

Answer (score 1):

Fick's law describes **diffusion flux**, which is :
$$ J=-D{\frac {d\varphi }{dx}} $$

,so when concentration $\varphi = \text {const}$, then $J = 0 \to$ and so, no diffusion flux.